# Kindle Fire: Google Services Framework

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, google-apps

So I rooted my fire using Burrito Root.

The SuperUser app was available once that was complete. I got a version of Google Services Framework from http://code.google.com/p/androidmarketu/downloads/list

When I try to install the Google Services Framework, it tries to install it but then it says "Not Installed".

I have the Allow Other Applications set to ON.

I don't wish to change the stock ROM. 
All I need is the Google Talk application to work on the Kindle Fire.

Comment: If you have `adb` configured on your computer you can use it to get a more detailed error message about why the install is failing (if you want). You'd do this by downloading the .apk file to your computer, plugging in your Kindle, and then running `adb install /path/to/apk`.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to install the google services framework just with root. I installed it on my Kindle Fire via TWRP (a bootloader/recovery alternative), by downloading the update.zip (the link can be found on XDA) and selecting it in TWRP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kindle Fire Utility](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1399889) provides an easy and automated way to get root, Android Market with other Google Apps including Google Services Framework.

Alternatively, you can use quite nice [imo messenger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052AZJV8) to connect to GTalk, Skype, etc even with no root.

Comment: I am going with IMO messenger for now. Thanks for the link.